# IronPython examples

Tags: python, ironpython

I have heard IronPython for a long time, but never seen a real-life application using it.

Do you provide some examples to see its power?

Thanks.

Comment: Please define "real-life".  If people are using it, they're using it in reality.  In real life.  Yet, somehow, people using it isn't real enough.  What level of reality are you looking for?  Please define the threshold that has to be crossed for you to consider it "real life".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you miss [Resolver Systems](http://www.resolversystems.com/)? Their [Rsolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-one/) spreadsheet application is IronPython.